# How does the Ubuntu Server installer get my ssh key from Github?

Tags: server, ssh, github

I couldn't find a way to get my or other people's public key from Github, but the Ubuntu Server installer can.

How can it and how could I get an ssh public key via GitHub username in a script myself?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
curl -O https://github.com/<username>.keys 
curl -O https://gitlab.com/<username>.keys
```

will retrieve the public keys uploaded for the given username. Both github and gitlab work.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen sorry I found it in my personal documents with a reference to a U+L link but not documentation.

Comment: Indeed. github.com and gitlab.com don't store the secret key, so it's impossible to retrieve that one.

Comment: Very useful, but how can I tell them apart? I  have multiple SSH keys on my account.

Answer (score 9):

In this particular instance [ssh-import-id](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ssh-import-id) retrieves an SSH key from GitHub for you.  The tool can import from both GitHub and Launchpad.  Normally the tool takes the retrieved key and adds it to your authorized keys file which is what Ubuntu Server would have been doing.  The manual page [outlines the mechanics of the specific API calls it makes to retrieve the key](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/ssh-import-id.1.html).

Comment: Is there ssh-import-id for Red Hat based systems as well? I couldn't find it in the default repositories for CentOS (epel) & Fedora.

Comment: @u15p7fgy863eiq5 The utility was written by Dustin Kirkland so it is a solution born in the Ubuntu world.  To use it in the Red Hat-based world you could secure it via PyPi: https://pypi.org/project/ssh-import-id/.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Rinzwind's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1199559/653515), [Github has an API for this](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/keys/).

The API is *not* the URL described by Rinzwind, but it appears to be in addition to that.

Comment: gitlab: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/

Answer (score 1):

The exact usage is `ssh-import-id gh:github_username`

See the [manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ssh-import-id.1.html)